# using Jquery loop - while retriving the data, the order is missing

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have a array, it has 4 child array, i am trying to retrive the data from each array with a scond delayed, as well from the array i need the each element retrived 1 sec delayed.

i made a function, which works but the order of data is not correct, any one correct this function to get proper ordered data with 1 sec delayer each.

as well i understand my function is some what bigger. any give me the very short way to achieve the same result.

function:

```
var ar = [

    [
        Object= { el:'li',  x:0,  y:294},
        Object= { el:'li',  x:150,  y:294},
        Object= { el:'li',  x:300,  y:294}
    ],

    [
        Object= { el:'li',  x:0,  y:196},
        Object= { el:'li',  x:150, y:196},
        Object= { el:'li',  x:300, y:196}
    ],

    [
        Object= { el:'li',  x:0,  y:98},
        Object= { el:'li',  x:150,  y:98},
        Object= { el:'li',  x:300,  y:98}
    ],

    [
        Object= { el:'li',  x:0,  y:0},
        Object= { el:'li',  x:150,  y:0},
        Object={ el:'li',  x:300,  y:0}
    ]

]

    var length = ar.length;

for(i=0;i<length;i++){

    (function(i){

 setTimeout(function(){

     var minLength = ar[i].length;

     for(j=0;j<minLength;j++){
         (function(d){
             setTimeout(function(j){
                 console.log(ar[d][d])
             },1000*d)             

         })(j)
     }

    },2000*i)


    })(i)
}
```

i am just consoling the result.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pxq7g/)

Comment: `console.log(ar[d][d])` will only print the diagonal.

Comment: i can't get you, actually at present i am printing. i will take this out in to animation.

Comment: `ar[d][d]` means `ar[0][0]`, `ar[1][1]`, `ar[2][2]`...

Comment: perhaps you wanted `ar[i][d]`?

Comment: is it the reason, for the wrong orders. let me correct and check. but my way of function is correct?

Comment: Your code will start printing each row every two seconds, one element in each row every second. This means `i=0, j=2` will get printed at the same time as `i=1, j=0`.

Comment: If every `a[i]` has exactly three elements, you can do `i*3000` to get the timing of one element per second, read by rows.

Comment: Is your goal to display one element per second, ordered by rows?

Comment: yes. because i am doing a animation

Comment: Does the animation take exactly one second as well, by any means?

Comment: yes, it's like falling the logos from the top. but dynamic calculation is the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pick one element per second, you can chain the callbacks. After each element, animate the next one in the row, or, if there is none, the first one in the next (non-empty) row. This has the benefit that any delay will propagate to the subsequent animation:

```
var ar /* = ... */;

var i = 0;
var j = 0;

(function next(){
   console.log(ar[i][j]);
   j++;
   while(ar[i] && !ar[i][j]){ //can be optimised if every row has at least one element
     i++;
     j=0;
   }
   if(ar[i]){
     setTimeout(next);
   }
 })();
```

If every animation step takes exactly one second, then it's better to attach `next` to the finish handler of the animation to ensure the animations won't overlap (jQuery supports that).

```
(function next(){
   j++;
   while(ar[i] && !ar[i][j]){ //can be optimised if every row has at least one element
     i++;
     j=0;
   }
   $(/*...*/).animate({/*...*/}, 1000, ar[i] ? next : null);
 })();
```

Comment: are you made it to work by rows(each array are rows i have 4 rows)right? if so this is great. let me check. thanks

Comment: Each row is fully iterated over before the the next one starts being iterated over, each second one element is chosen. Either the next element in the row, or the first element in the next row.

Comment: That's good. Thanks i am on implementation. once i get result, let you know. thanks again.